# Find probability and expected length

Tags: probability

A piece of timber 4.2m long has to be cut into two pieces fit into a van to take home. Each must be at least 1.8m long in order to be useful. The cut can be anywhere between the 1.8m marks from each end. Considering the shorter piece, find the probability that it is less than 2m long and expected length.

So this is what i have tried, to find probability i did 4.2-1.8-1.8=0.6 0.6/4.2*2=14.3 which is not correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Some hints.

1. What are the minimum and maximum lengths of the shorter piece?
2. Plot the length of the shorter piece as a function of the distance of the cut from one end (the left end, say). The function will be non-zero in between $1.8$ meters and $4.2 - 1.8 = 2.4$ meters, and zero outside that interval.
3. Under the assumption that any valid cut is equally likely, and looking at the graph, what does this say about the likelihood of getting any particular valid length for the shorter piece? (Is $1.85$ meters less likely, as likely, or more likely than, say, $2.05$ meters?)

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Is it equally likely? Because he cant make any length as long as it is above or equal to 1.8 right?